# Sphinx operator "less"

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, search, sphinx

I want... My english is bad - look example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE price < 1000
```

How can I do it with sphinx (database PostgreSQL)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SetFilterRange('price', 0, 1000);

or

SetSelect('price < 1000 as fil');
SetFilter('price', array(1));